# PySpark to Pandas Dataframe conversion :Error in data types while converting

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

Lets assume I have a dataframe `abc` in spark as follows:

```
ID    Trxn_Date    Order_Date    Sales_Rep  Order_Category   Sales_Amount   Discount
100   2021-03-24   2021-03-17    Mathew     DailyStaples       1000           1.50
133   2021-01-22   2021-01-12    Camelia    Medicines          2000           0.50
```

**Objective:**

Pick up a *column randomly for each data type* and find its minimum and maximum value column wise.

```
  - For `numerical` column it should also compute the sum or average.
  - For `string` column it should compute the maximum and minimum length
```

Create another dataframe with the following structure:

```
Table_Name        Column_Name         Min              Max     Sum
  abc              Trxn_Date      2021-01-22   2021-03-24
  abc              Sales_Rep            6              7              <----str.len('Mathew') = 6 and that of 'Camelia' is 7
  abc              Sales_Amount       1000            2000     3000
```

I am using the following code but it is picking up *all the columns*. Also when I am running this in *databrics / PySpark* environment, I am getting error as given below.

```
table_lst = ['table_1','table_2']
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.execution.arrow.enabled", "true")
df_list = []
for i in table_lst:
  sdf_i = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM schema_name.{0}".format(i))
  df_i = sdf_i.select("*").toPandas()
df_list.append(df_i)
d = {}
for i,j in zip(table_name,dfs):
   d[i] = j
df_concat = []
for k,v in d.items():
   val_df = {}
   for i,j in zip(v.columns,v.dtypes):
     if 'object' in str(j):
        max_s = v[i].map(len).max()
        min_s = v[i].map(len).min()
        val_df[k+'-'+i+'_'+'Max_String_L']= max_s
        val_df[k+'-'+i+'_'+'Min_String_L']= min_s
     elif 'int' or 'float' in str(j):
        max_int = v[i].max()      <------Error line as indicated in Databricks
        min_int = v[i].min()
        val_df[k+'-'+i+'Max_Num'] = max_int
        val_df[k+'-'+i+'_'+'Min_Num'] = min_int
     elif 'datetime' in str(j):
        max_date = v[i].max()
        min_date = v[i].min()
        val_df[k+'-'+i+'_'+'Max_Date'] = max_date
        val_df[k+'-'+i+'_'+'Min_Date'] = min_date
     else:
        print('left anythg?')
  df_f_d = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(val_df,orient='index').reset_index()
  df_concat.append(df_f_d)
```

When I am running this code on databrics pyspark, I am getting the below error:

```
 TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'
```

Besides, the above code is not throwing the resultant dataframe as indicated above.

My suspicion is while converting the `sparkDF` to `pandas`, all data types are being convereted to `string`.

How to, then, tackle this issue? Also can the above code be modified so that the objective is fulfilled?

Answer (score 0):

My solution is a bit long (probably expected as per the requirement), you can debug it with each step as you want. The overall idea is

1. Distinguse which column is string, which column is numerical
2. using `describe` function to get min max of each column.
3. `describe`, however, doesn't calculate sum and average so we have to aggregate separately

```py
# a.csv
# ID,Trxn_Date,Order_Date,Sales_Rep,Order_Category,Sales_Amount,Discount
# 100,2021-03-24,2021-03-17,Mathew,DailyStaples,1000,1.50
# 133,2021-01-22,2021-01-12,Camelia,Medicines,2000,0.50

from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = spark.read.csv('a.csv', header=True, inferSchema=True
all_cols = [col[0] for col in df.dtypes]
date_cols = ['Trxn_Date', 'Order_Date'] # Spark doesn't infer DateType so I have to handle it manually. You can ignore if your original schema already has it.
str_cols = [col[0] for col in df.dtypes if col[1] == 'string' and col[0] not in date_cols]
num_cols = [col[0] for col in df.dtypes if col[1] in ['int', 'double']]

# replace actual string values with its length
for col in str_cols:
    df = df.withColumn(col, F.length(col))

# calculate min max and transpose dataframe
df1 = (df
    .describe()
    .where(F.col('summary').isin('min', 'max'))
    .withColumn('keys', F.array([F.lit(c) for c in all_cols]))
    .withColumn('values', F.array([F.col(c) for c in all_cols]))
    .withColumn('maps', F.map_from_arrays('keys', 'values'))
    .select('summary', F.explode('maps').alias('col', 'value'))
    .groupBy('col')
    .agg(
        F.collect_list('summary').alias('keys'),
        F.collect_list('value').alias('values')
    )
    .withColumn('maps', F.map_from_arrays('keys', 'values'))
    .select('col', 'maps.min', 'maps.max')
)
df1.show(10, False)
# +--------------+----------+----------+
# |col           |min       |max       |
# +--------------+----------+----------+
# |Sales_Amount  |1000      |2000      |
# |Sales_Rep     |6         |7         |
# |Order_Category|9         |12        |
# |ID            |100       |133       |
# |Discount      |0.5       |1.5       |
# |Trxn_Date     |2021-01-22|2021-03-24|
# |Order_Date    |2021-01-12|2021-03-17|
# +--------------+----------+----------+

# calculate sum and transpose dataframe
df2 = (df
    .groupBy(F.lit(1).alias('sum'))
    .agg(*[F.sum(c).alias(c) for c in num_cols])
    .withColumn('keys', F.array([F.lit(c) for c in num_cols]))
    .withColumn('values', F.array([F.col(c) for c in num_cols]))
    .withColumn('maps', F.map_from_arrays('keys', 'values'))
    .select(F.explode('maps').alias('col', 'sum'))
)
df2.show(10, False)
# +------------+------+
# |col         |sum   |
# +------------+------+
# |ID          |233.0 |
# |Sales_Amount|3000.0|
# |Discount    |2.0   |
# +------------+------+

# Join them together to get final dataframe
df1.join(df2, on=['col'], how='left').show()
# +--------------+----------+----------+------+
# |           col|       min|       max|   sum|
# +--------------+----------+----------+------+
# |  Sales_Amount|      1000|      2000|3000.0|
# |     Sales_Rep|         6|         7|  null|
# |Order_Category|         9|        12|  null|
# |            ID|       100|       133| 233.0|
# |      Discount|       0.5|       1.5|   2.0|
# |     Trxn_Date|2021-01-22|2021-03-24|  null|
# |    Order_Date|2021-01-12|2021-03-17|  null|
# +--------------+----------+----------+------+
```